# how to import javascript ES6 repo compiled output into other repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, npm

i have two github javascript repos, "chromeextention" repo and "core" repo.

I want "chromeextention" repo to consume the build output of "core" repo(since "core" repo is writen in ES6 it need to be compiled to ES5 for using it).

The question is: how to get compiled output of "core" repo to be imported to "chromeextention" repo after running "npm install" command in the "chromeextention" repo?

P. S. How this done in jquery repo for example?

Thanks

Comment: "I want" does not get. What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi, i tried git "submodules" - which i think exactly for this purpose, but it only importing the whole core repo without compile it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding following code to package.json of "core" repo

```
"files":["dist/core.js"]
```

and running **npm publish** 
and adding "core" repo as dependency

in chreomeextention repo